# Установка бота в телеграмм написаного на питоне

Tags: python, telebot, бот

Всем привет! Мне выдает вот такую ошибку при запуске бота, но проблема вся в том, что у меня все это стоит. Пожалуйста, помогите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
File "C:\Users\DSDS\Desktop\sms_tg_bot test\main.py", line 4, in <module>
  import menu
File "C:\Users\DSDS\Desktop\sms_tg_bot test\menu.py", line 1, in <module>
  from telebot import types
ImportError: cannot import name 'types' from 'telebot' (C:\Users\DSDS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py
```

Answer (score 1):

а пробовали импортировать модуль "telebot" полностью?

Answer (score 1):

HAKER JOP,
1)Попробуй переустановить пакет telebot(если не помогает перейди на версию 2.8 там работает)
2)Как я понял ты пытаешься импортировать menu, попробуй from menu import *

Comment: Не до конца замазал XD .Спасибо помогло